# Dynamic Date Interval Filter Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to fulfill a requirement where client wants to select data from elasticsearch and get document count split by date intervals which may be changed.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WllwG.jpg - I want to select all documents that have start/end in given interval (1.1. - 31.1.)

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I8g6.jpg - Example desired result (kibana chart)

I have documents that look like this, each of them have startDate and optionally endDate - meaning request was not finished yet.

```
{
  "_index": "bpm-aggregate-19.07",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "b80b708c-d617-4dd4-89cd-6f1efeef927a.ebab442f-d9ad-423f-862c-d803eae3c99a.7330.28",
  "_version": 33,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "bpm": {
      "sequenceId": 33
    },
    "source": {
      "bpm": {
        "version": "2064.117680c1-e266-4dac-ae23-fb8bf948003a",
        "name": "Check Request"
      },
      "parent": {
        "parent": {
          "bpm": {
            "version": "2064.117680c1-e266-4dac-ae23-fb8bf948003a",
            "name": "Payment Order",
            "documentation": ""
          },
          "id": "c1c49bbe-b5f2-4c49-9dd6-7812a94d8ba3",
          "type": "wle:processApplication"
        },
        "id": "b80b708c-d617-4dd4-89cd-6f1efeef927a",
        "instance": {
          "bpm": {
            "state": "Active"
          },
          "id": "7330"
        },
        "type": "bpmn:process"
      },
      "id": "99bc462b-312d-43d0-8548-715b19f6ee5b",
      "type": "bpmn:userTask"
    },
    "context": {
      "bpm": {
        "starting-process-instance": "b80b708c-d617-4dd4-89cd-6f1efeef927a.ebab442f-d9ad-423f-862c-d803eae3c99a.7330"
      },
      "trace-id": "3f605c67-1e21-47bb-91b3-b87cd24d26da",
      "span-id": "8d07ccec45054267"
    },
    "@taskCompletedOverdue": 1,
    "task": {
      "user": {
        "bpm": {
          "name": "John Doe"
        },
        "id": "jdoe3"
      },
      "time": {
        "complete": "2019-07-29T10:17:39.823Z",
        "start": "2019-07-29T05:08:02.180Z",
        "open": "2019-07-29T10:17:23.930Z",
        "assign": "2019-07-29T05:08:02.340Z"
      },
      "kpi": {
        "timeToCompleteFromOpen": 0.26488333333333336,
        "timeToComplete": 309.62738333333334,
        "timeToFirstOpen": 309.3598333333333
      },
      "name": "Check Request",
      "state": "Completed",
      "team": {
        "bpm": {
          "name": "All Users"
        },
        "id": "All Users_T_da7e4d23-78cb-4483-98ed-b9c238308a03.d158d9ca-4d62-4c73-9ddd-dfa70b37f398"
      }
    },
    "@lastUpdateEventType": "bpmnx:ACTIVITY_COMPLETED",
    "@timestamp": "2019-07-29T10:17:40.293Z",
    "system": {
      "bpm": {
        "bpmCellName": "bpmWorfklowCenterCell01"
      },
      "id": "ebab442f-d9ad-423f-862c-d803eae3c99a"
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "category": "bpmnx:BPD",
    "business-events-extension-version": "bpmn/1.0.0",
    "business-events-envelope-version": "1.0.0",
    "@lastUpdateEventSequenceId": 33,
    "@lastUpdateTime": "2019-07-29T12:17:39.823+02:00"
  }
}
```

So far, I have came up with following Lucene Queries, however they have hardcoded date ranges (that is what I am trying to get rid off)

```
(task.time.start: [* TO now-1d/d] && task.time.complete: [now-1d/d TO now/d]) || (task.time.start: [now-1d/d TO now/d] && task.time.complete: [now/d TO *]) || (task.time.start: [now-1d/d TO now/d] && task.time.complete: [now-1d/d TO now/d]) || (task.time.start: [now-1d/d TO now/d])
```

```
(task.time.start: [* TO now-2d/d] && task.time.complete: [now-2d/d TO now-1d/d]) || (task.time.start: [now-2d/d TO now-1/d] && task.time.complete: [now-1d/d TO *]) || (task.time.start: [now-2d/d TO now-1d/d] && task.time.complete: [now-2d/d TO now-1d/d]) || (task.time.start: [now-2d/d TO now-1d/d])
```

...

and so on for each interval. This seems to work perfectly fine, however this is highly impractical. If we the interval we want is for example a month, I need to modify these filters for each day in the month. If anyone wanted to see data by month for past year, I'd need to create new set of queries.

Is there easier way to do this?

Comment: have you looked at `aggregation ranges or aggregation histograms`? can you also post a couple sample documents?

Comment: @JBone thank you for the hint. I have added whole example of the document. I have been looked at both ranges and aggregation histograms, the problem seems to be, that I am unable to apply filter per bucket. E.g. If I aggregate by date and interval is 1 month, I need to filter documents that have start date or end date in that interval. See the lucene queries I have added.